# Verificar se uma string contém números, em C++

Tags: c++

Como pegar o resultado da string nome e fazer uma verificaçao, para saber se conten numeros.

Ate fiz um codigozinho, mas, a cada caractere digitada, ele me retorna VARIAS vezes o if.

````
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int idade;
    string nome;
    cout << "digite seu nome: ";
    getline(cin, nome);
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <  nome.length(); i++)
        {
            if (!isdigit(nome[i]))
            {
                cout << "deu certo";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "deu errado";
            }
        }

        
    }
    cout << "digite sua idade:";
    cin >> idade;
    
    system("pause");

    
}```
````

Answer (score -3):

você colocou dentro do loop para escrever tal coisa ,  é lóGico que isso será escrito várias vezes mesmo , melhor seria colocar uma variável que ao ser detectado um digito na string atribua um valor a essa variável , e deixe para comparar se teve ou não um dígito na string após a execução do Loop , assim só irá escrever uma ùnica vez .
um exemplo :

```
#include    <string>
#include    <iostream>
#include    <ctype.h>
using namespace  std;
void        Getch();
int main    ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int idade;
    int flag = 0;
    string nome;
    cout << "digite seu nome: ";
    getline(cin, nome);

    for (int i = 0; i <  nome.length(); i++)
    {
        if ( isdigit( nome[i] ) )
        {
            flag = 1;        /// Marca como encontrado o dIgito na String
            break;           /// sai do Loop , pois encontrou um dIgito numErico na String
        }
    }
    if( flag > 0 )               /// flag eh apenas uma simples varAvel qq ,  
    {                        /// se ela for diferente de "zero"
        cout << "deu errado."; /// significa q tem dIgito numErico na String
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "deu certo.";
    }
    cout << endl << "digite sua idade:" << endl;
    cin >> idade;
    Getch();                /// essa funCAo existe na Biblioteca "conio.h"
                            /// mas nAo eh padrAo da linguagem C
    ///-------------------------------------------------------
    printf("\n\n\n");
    return   0;
}
void    Getch()  /// funCAo espera Uma tecla ser Pressionada e nAo retorna nada
{
    printf("\t\"Pressione uma Tecla.\"\n");
    FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
    WaitForSingleObject(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), INFINITE);
}
```